# Make this simple for/if block more pythonic

Tags: python

I need to store in a list the indexes of those values in 3 lists which exceed a given maximum limit. This is what I got:

```
# Data lists.
a = [3,4,5,12,6,8,78,5,6]
b = [6,4,1,2,8,784,43,6,2]
c = [8,4,32,6,1,7,2,9,23]

# Maximum limit.
max_limit = 20.

# Store indexes in list.
indexes = []
for i, a_elem in enumerate(a):
    if a_elem > max_limit or b[i] > max_limit or c[i] > max_limit:
        indexes.append(i)
```

This works but I find it quite ugly. How can I make it more elegant/pythonic?

Comment: A large bit of the ugly comes from hiding the relatedness of (a[i], b[i], c[i]) in parallel lists. Perhaps a [namedtuple](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple) would make the data conform better to your use.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could replace your `for` loop with:

```
indexes = []
for i, triplet in enumerate(zip(a, b, c)):
    if any(e > max_limit for e in triplet):
        indexes.append(i)
```

... which you *could* then reduce to a list comprehension:

```
indexes = [i for i, t in enumerate(zip(a, b, c)) if any(e > max_limit for e in t)]
```

... although that seems a little unwieldy to me - this is really about personal taste, but I prefer to keep listcomps simple; the three-line `for` loop is clearer in my opinion.

As pointed out by user2357112, you can reduce the apparent complexity of the list comprehension with `max()`:

```
indexes = [i for i, t in enumerate(zip(a, b, c)) if max(t) > max_limit]
```

... although this won't short-circuit in the same way that the `any()` version (and your own code) does, so will probably be slightly slower.

Comment: Using `max(triplet) > max_limit` is simpler than `any` and cuts the list comprehension down to a more understandable form.

Comment: @user2357112 True (at the cost of extra computation - `any()` short-circuits in the same way that OP's `or` solution does). Will add a `max()` version for completeness ...

Answer (score 2):

You could try

```
if max(a_elem, b[i], c[i]) > max_limit:
    indexes.append(i)
```

The logic here is finding out if any one of these three values needs to be greater than max_limit.  If the greatest element of these three is greater than max_limit, your condition is satisfied.

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> maximums = map(max, zip(a, b, c))
>>> [i for i, num in enumerate(maximums) if num > max_limit]
[2, 5, 6, 8]
```

**Old answer**

Previously, I posted the mess below. The list comp above is much more manageable.

```
>>> next(zip(*filter(lambda i: i[1] > max_limit, enumerate(map(max, zip(a, b, c))))))
(2, 5, 6, 8)
```

Answer (score 2):

I like the `exceeders =` line best myself

```
import collections

# Data lists.
a = [3,4,5,12,6,8,78,5,6]
b = [6,4,1,2,8,784,43,6,2]
c = [8,4,32,6,1,7,2,9,23]

Triad = collections.namedtuple('Triad', 'a b c')
triads = [Triad(*args) for args in zip(a, b, c)]

triads = [t for t in zip(a, b, c)]  # if you don't need namedtuple

# Maximum limit.
max_limit = 20.

# Store indexes in list.
indexes = [for i, t in enumerate(triads) if max(t) > max_limit]
print indexes

# store the bad triads themselves in a list for
# greater pythonic

exceeders = [t for t in triads if max(t) > max_limit]
print exceeder
```

As I commented above, using parallel arrays to represent data that are related makes simple code much less simple than it need be.

**added in response to comment**

Perhaps I gave you too many alternatives, so I shall give only one way instead. One feature that all of the answers have in common is that they fuse the separate "data lists" into rows using zip:

```
triads = [t for t in zip(a, b, c)]
exceeders = [t for t in triads if max(t) > max_limit]
```

That's it: two lines. The important point is that storing the index of anything in a list is a C-style way of doing things and you asked for a Pythonic way. Keeping a list of indices means that anytime you want to do something with the data at that index, you have to do an indirection. After those two lines execute, `exceeders` has the value:

```
[(5, 1, 32), (8, 784, 7), (78, 43, 2), (6, 2, 23)]
```

Where each member of the list has the "column" of your three data rows that was found to exceed your limit.

Now you might say "but I really wanted the indices instead". If that is so, there is another part of your problem which you didn't show us which also relies on list indexing. If so, you are still doing things in a C/C++/Java way and "Pythonic" will remain evasive.

Comment: I'm sure this must have a lot of benefits but I find it tremendously complicated.

Comment: @Gabriel, please see "added" above in which I reduced the tremendous complexity for you.

Answer (score 1):

```
m = lambda l: [i for i, e in enumerate(l) if e>max_limit]
indexes = sorted(set(m(a) + m(b) + m(c)))
```