# numpy.delete changing arrays of floats to strings

Tags: python, arrays, string, numpy

I'm using the `numpy.delete` function to remove elements from several arrays. I started from this question [Make this simple for/if block more pythonic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23706447/make-this-simple-for-if-block-more-pythonic) and arrived, after applying the answer given there, to this:

```
# Data lists.
a = [3,4,5,12,6,8,78,5,6]
b = [6,4,1.,2,8,784.,43,6.,2]
c = [8,4.,32.,6,1,7,2.,9,23]

# Maximum limit.
max_limit = 20.

# Store indexes of elements to be removed.
indexes = [i for i, t in enumerate(zip(b, c)) if any(e > max_limit for e in t)]

# Remove elements from all lists.
big_array = np.array([a, b, c])
clean_array = np.delete(big_array, indexes, axis=1)

# Final clean lists.
a_clean, b_clean, c_clean = clean_array
```

The issue I'm having is that one of my lists is actually made of *strings* rather than floats, like this:

```
# Data lists.
a = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i'] # <-- strings
b = [6,4,1.,2,8,784.,43,6.,2] # <-- floats
c = [8,4.,32.,6,1,7,2.,9,23] # <-- floats
```

and when I apply the code above the `numpy.delete` line converts all elements in *all final lists* (`a_clean, b_clean, c_clean`) to strings rather than preserving only the first one as strings and the rest as floats.

How can I prevent this from happening or fix it if it can't be helped?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are going to use numpy, you are going to be better off converting your lists to arrays. It would look something like:

```
a = np.array(a)
b = np.array(b)
c = np.array(c)

mask = (b > max_limit) | (c > max_limit)

a = a[mask]
b = b[mask]
c = c[mask]

>>> a
array(['c', 'f', 'g', 'i'],
      dtype='|S1')
>>> b
array([   1.,  784.,   43.,    2.])
>>> c
array([ 32.,   7.,   2.,  23.])
```