# Append array to beginning of another array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm attempting to perform a simple task: append an array to the beginning of another array. Here a MWE of what I mean:

```
a = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i']
b = [6,4,1.,2,8,784.,43,6.,2]
c = [8,4.,32.,6,1,7,2.,9,23]

# Define arrays.
a_arr = np.array(a)
bc_arr = np.array([b, c])

# Append a_arr to beginning of bc_arr
print np.concatenate((a_arr, bc_arr), axis=1)
```

but I keep getting a `ValueError: all the input arrays must have same number of dimensions` error.

The arrays `a_arr` and `bc_arr` come like that from a different process so I can't manipulate the way they are created (ie: I can't use the `a,b,c` lists).

How can I generate a new array of `a_arr` and `bc_arr` so that it will look like:

```
array(['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i'], [6,4,1.,2,8,784.,43,6.,2], [8,4.,32.,6,1,7,2.,9,23])
```

Comment: Can I ask why you're using a `numpy` array to store mixed datatypes, especially `char`s? I'm not sure most of the `numpy` functionality would be available to you if you use it. Why not use a simple list or a custom class?

Comment: I'ts related to this question I made yesterday: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23707082/numpy-delete-changing-arrays-of-floats-to-strings

Comment: I still don't understand what advantage you'd have using a `numpy` array...

Comment: do b and c have to be joined when you create arrays?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham no, each initial array (`a_arr`, `bc_arr`) should stay as a sub-array within the final array like show in the question.

Comment: There is almost never a good reason to use numpy arrays with `dtype=object`. You would be better off using [structured arrays](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.rec.html) instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you do something like.

```
In [88]: a = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i']

In [89]: b = [6,4,1.,2,8,784.,43,6.,2]

In [90]: c = [8,4.,32.,6,1,7,2.,9,23]

In [91]: joined_arr=np.array([a_arr,b_arr,c_arr],dtype=object)

In [92]: joined_arr
Out[92]: 
array([['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i'],
       [6.0, 4.0, 1.0, 2.0, 8.0, 784.0, 43.0, 6.0, 2.0],
       [8.0, 4.0, 32.0, 6.0, 1.0, 7.0, 2.0, 9.0, 23.0]], dtype=object)
```

Comment: This seems to work, I can use `bc_arr` instead of `b_arr,c_arr`. Thanks.

Comment: No worries. I missed the need to keep `bc_arr` as it is.

Answer (score 1):

this should work

```
In [84]: a=np.atleast_2d(a).astype('object')

In [85]: b=np.atleast_2d(b).astype('object')

In [86]: c=np.atleast_2d(c).astype('object')

In [87]: np.vstack((a,b,c))
Out[87]:
array([[a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i],
       [6.0, 4.0, 1.0, 2.0, 8.0, 784.0, 43.0, 6.0, 2.0],
       [8.0, 4.0, 32.0, 6.0, 1.0, 7.0, 2.0, 9.0, 23.0]], dtype=object)
```